# Android Studio / Gradle test folder naming convention

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've seen a lot of tutorials and helper projects for doing testing on an Android Studio / Gradle project. I'm curious about the naming convention of the the test folder. I've seen two similar namings : `test` and `androidTest`. Is there any real difference? Is the IDE / Gradle framework treating these differently?

- app

  - src

    - androidTest

      - java
    - main

      - java
      - res

versus

- app

  - src

    - test

      - java
    - main

      - java
      - res

EDIT:

@jonalmeida So if I read that documentation correctly, my `build.gradle` file dependencies need to match the sourceSet, right?

```
dependencies {
    // dependency injection
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'

    // networking
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'

    // testing
    androidTestCompile 'org.easytesting:fest:1.0.16'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8' // <---- this guy won't work 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Android Studio 1.1 you should put your Unit tests in `/src/test` and Android Instrumentation Tests in `/src/androidTest`

See: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Setting-up-Android-Studio

For Android Studio 2.0 and beyond see: https://youtu.be/kL3MCQV2M2s?t=114

Comment: I think you and @jonalmeida are both correct:  `/src/test` for unit tests (unit test support looks there) and `src/androidTest` for intergration (espresso looks there)

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out. You can switch between which tests you want to run by opening the `Build Variants` pane and selecting the Test Artifact: `Android Instrumentation Tests` or `Unit Tests`.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio the convention to follow for tests is to use `androidTest`. You can find more details documented on the [Android Tools site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure).